# Material UI dataGrid performance

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am trying to use Material UI data grid to display option chains. Essentially, I am creating 4 datagrids, each with 172 rows, and a page size of 100 (so about 700 total rows). To load the 4 grids, or to select and unselect values in the table, can easily take a few seconds. Being that they claim this comes with "blazing fast" performance, I am wondering if material ui data grid can actually handle this? Is there anything within the data grid I can use to improve my performance? Or is there an issue with my code (I am aware I am not providing code, it should not be relevant; if others are experiencing material UI is good for this kind of work, then I know its my code)?

Answer (score 5):

Material UI has been an amazing framework and it handles DataGrid pretty well.
As the code is not available, cannot comment on the performance of what you are looking for but yes as per my experience its blazingly fast.

Also as per the details you have given, loading so much data at once will definitely take some time. So, try loading in smaller chunks at first if this can be done else if MUI fails, there are other alternatives too if you wish to explore:

[1. Material Table](https://material-table.com/#/)

[2. React Table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/)

[3. Ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)

These are easy to use and fast too.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give my code another read over, maybe its my fault

Comment: Thanks Krishna, is there any way to compare the performance of available grids?

Comment: Check this link - https://www.debugbear.com/blog/measuring-react-app-performance